# NoSQL partitioning on non-primary key

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, nosql, partitioning

I am designing a chat application using NoSQL database like MongoDb/Cassandra.
The most time sensitive query would be finding messages belonging to a chat.

I get that there will be a `Message` collection, but not sure how to partition this collection based on chatId. I guess even `clustered index` will not be suitable for this type of use case.

Let's assume that `Message` will be following structure:

```
{
  "chatId"  : 123,
  "messageId"      : 456,
  "text"    : "Hello World!"
}
```

I think the only way is to partition on `messageId` and search for the messages for a chat in all partitions.

Comment: "search for the messages for a chat in all partitions."  As all data in a partition is guaranteed to be on the same node, querying multiple partitions will hit multiple nodes.  In NoSQL query time is network time, and in a large cluster "search...in all partitions" is a bad design.  In fact, I would hope that you would be *querying* and not *searching*.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, a traditional RDBMS schema for a messaging application should look like this.

### Chat

id
participant_id

### Messages

id
chat_id
from_id
text

I am guessing that you do not want to use RDBMS database probably because of some Infra limitation but I will seriously suggest to consider it for your use-case.
If I have to design something similar for NoSQL system like Cassandra, I will try to denormalize data as much as possible and design schema based on the query which will be used the most.

I will create one table with schema:
chat_id
message_id
message_text
Primary Key(chat_id,message_id)

Here chat_id is the partitioning key and message_id is clustering key. You can get all the messages related to a chat within a partition by querying by chat_id. Also, I will use TimeUUID for message ID, which will help in getting the latest N messages in a chat as you can run the limit filter on the clustering key.
If you still want the functionality to query message by message ID also, you can create a view on the main table with message_id as the primary key.

Comment: Exactly!  RDBMS would work fine for something like this.